# Avoid trimming all leading / padding chars with Parse::FixedLength

Tags: perl

I am using [Parse::FixedLength](http://search.cpan.org/~dougw/Parse-FixedLength-5.39/FixedLength.pm) and I would like to remove leading `0`s while parsing but unfortunately when the entire string is made up of `0`s it returns a blank value. This means I cannot distinguish between a bad input (blank) and post processed blank one.

```
    use Parse::FixedLength;

    my $parser = Parse::FixedLength->new([
            first_name => '10:1:10',
            last_name  => '10:11:20',
            widgets_this_month => '5R0:21:25',
    ], {trim => '1'});

    while (<DATA>) {
            warn "No record terminator found!\n" unless chomp;
            warn "Short Record!\n" unless $parser->length == length;
            my $data = $parser->parse($_);
            print $data->{'widgets_this_month'},$/;
    }
    __DATA__
    JOHN      SMITH     00005
    BOB       JONES     00000
    JOE       STAN      00117
    BLANK     WIDGET
    JANE      DOE       00007
```

Output is (< blank > below is empty string):

```
5
<blank>
117
<blank>
7
```

I want the output to be:

```
5
0
117
<blank>
7
```

Any thoughts on how I can achieve this? Btw, the above is a toy example from the module. My actual file has over 1200 fields with almost everyone (not all) has leading `0`s.

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason not to just leave them untrimmed?

Comment: @ysth These files are pretty big (20+GB) and most fields have padding chars. Not retaining the padding chars will help cut the size down and allow me to read it in down stream programs without handling padding chars there. I can leave them untrimmed and then trim after parsing is complete but then I will have to loop through all the fields and remove padding, which is quite cumbersome.  If there is a cleaner post processing solution, that will work as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no. There is no way to make `Parser::FixedLength` not read all the 0's when trimming a zero padded field. This is the regular expression that it sets for trimming:

```
'TPAD' => ARRAY(0x7fb378979a08)
   0  (?^:^0+)
      -> qr/(?^:^0+)/
```

So it reads all the zeros. You can however abuse this internal data structure and make a hack that will achieve what you are looking for:

`$parser->{TPAD}[0] = qr/^0+(?=\d)/;`

This will set the trim regular expression to have a positive look-ahead for another digit, so it will save at least one digit when Parser::FixedLength trims it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works. I will document that this line is a hack.