# Parse::FixedLength Trimming Issue

Tags: perl

In my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409469/avoid-trimming-all-leading-padding-chars-with-parsefixedlength) I had asked how to avoid Parse::FixedLength from trimming all zeros. The code @bolav suggested worked for the sample data I was using but somehow it does not seem to work for my new data.

It seems like it should work but somehow it is trimming all zeros for this data. It is likely I am making a very obvious mistake but I cannot figure out what it is. Appreciate your help.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use strict;
    use warnings; 
    use Parse::FixedLength;
    use Data::Dumper;

    my $parser = Parse::FixedLength->new([
              field1 => '12R0:1:12',
              field2 => '2:13:14',
              field3 => '5R0:15:19',
              field4 => '10R0:20:29',
              field5 => '2R0:30:31',
              field6 => '3R0:32:34'
              ], {trim => '1'});

    $parser->{TPAD}[0] = qr/^0+(?=\d)/;   # Modification suggested by @bolav

    while (<DATA>) {
        warn "No record terminator found!\n" unless chomp;
        warn "Short Record!\n" unless $parser->length == length;
        my $data = $parser->parse($_);
        print Dumper $data;
    }
    __DATA__
    119401122910XX42152931177771001000
    119401122910XX42152931177771001010
```

The last field should be `0` and `10` but it outputs `blank` and `10`. **Update**: I don't want the output for `field6` to be `000` and `010` -- I can get that just by removing the `trim` option. The regex is supposed to fix this issue but for some reason it is not doing that.

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'field1' => '119401122910',
                 'field6' => '',
                 'field4' => '9311777710',
                 'field2' => 'XX',
                 'field3' => '42152',
                 'field5' => '1'
               }, 'Parse::FixedLength::HashAsObj::Href1' );
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'field1' => '119401122910',
                 'field6' => '10',
                 'field4' => '9311777710',
                 'field2' => 'XX',
                 'field3' => '42152',
                 'field5' => '1'
               }, 'Parse::FixedLength::HashAsObj::Href1' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Okay I've read your original question and understand better what it is you're wanting. You really should make each question stand on its own -- Stack Overflow isn't a forum

The reason the suggested modification doesn't work for this configuration is that `$parser->{TPAD}` is an *array* of regular expressions to be removed from the front of each *justified* field. In your case it's all the fields except `field2`. You are modifying only the first element of the array, so you are fixing only `field1`

Here's a more generalised modification that changes *every* element of the `$parser->{TPAD}` array so that it always leaves at least the final character of the field, whatever that is. Note that, if your padding character is a space in formats like `5R` then it will trim an all-space field down to a single space instead of emptying it

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Parse::FixedLength;
use Data::Dump;

my $parser = Parse::FixedLength->new(
    [   field1 => '12R0:1:12',
        field2 => '2:13:14',
        field3 => '5R0:15:19',
        field4 => '10R0:20:29',
        field5 => '2R0:30:31',
        field6 => '3R0:32:34'
    ],
    { trim => 1 }
);

$_ = qr/$_(?=.)/ for @{ $parser->{TPAD} };

while (<DATA>) {
    my $data = $parser->parse($_);
    dd $data;
}

__DATA__
119401122910XX42152931177771001000
119401122910XX42152931177771001010
```

### output

```
bless({
  field1 => 119401122910,
  field2 => "XX",
  field3 => 42152,
  field4 => 9311777710,
  field5 => 1,
  field6 => 0,
}, "Parse::FixedLength::HashAsObj::Href1")
bless({
  field1 => 119401122910,
  field2 => "XX",
  field3 => 42152,
  field4 => 9311777710,
  field5 => 1,
  field6 => 10,
}, "Parse::FixedLength::HashAsObj::Href1")
```

---

I notice that your code produces the result that you want if you simply remove the `trim => 1` option. However I presume you have reasons for wanting that in place so here is a solution

Since [`Parse::FixedLength`](http://metacpan.org/module/Parse::FixedLength) allows for [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) template elements to be used, you can explicitly specify an `A` field to get your data transferred literally. It's the same template as the module uses for the other fields, but it disables the `trim` option for that field

This code does as you ask

```
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    use Parse::FixedLength;
    use Data::Dump;

    my $parser = Parse::FixedLength->new([
              field1 => '12R0:1:12',
              field2 => '2:13:14',
              field3 => '5R0:15:19',
              field4 => '10R0:20:29',
              field5 => 'A2:30:31',
              field6 => 'A3:32:34'
              ], {trim => '1'});

    while ( <DATA> ) {
        my $data = $parser->parse($_);
        dd $data;
    }

    __DATA__
    119401122910XX42152931177771001000
    119401122910XX42152931177771001010
```

### output

```
    bless({
      field1 => 119401122910,
      field2 => "XX",
      field3 => 42152,
      field4 => 9311777710,
      field5 => "01",
      field6 => "000",
    }, "Parse::FixedLength::HashAsObj::Href1")
    bless({
      field1 => 119401122910,
      field2 => "XX",
      field3 => 42152,
      field4 => 9311777710,
      field5 => "01",
      field6 => "010",
    }, "Parse::FixedLength::HashAsObj::Href1")
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to trim the `0` padding from the input data and that's why I am using `trim`. In my previous question, @bolav's update to the regex solved the problem. However, when I apply it to a different data, it seems to have an issue and I have no idea why that's the case. I would like my `field6` output to be `0` instead of `blank` or `000` and `10` and not `010`. Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks again. I realized the question is not a clear stand alone after you responded. Thanks for looking into it again and solving this problem for me. I thought I need to change the entire `TPAD` array and I did try to print that array but for whatever reason, I just recall seeing one element so I thought it probably applies for all fields and kept breaking my head over why the logic is not working.

Comment: @Ecognium: You can print the `TPAD` array with `print "$_\n" for @{ $parser->{TPAD} }`

Answer (score 1):

You can just replace values that have been trimmed down to the bone with 0:

```
my $data = $parser->parse($_);

for my $val (values %$data) {
    $val =~ s/^$/0/  #If the val is blank, replace with a 0
}
```

Here's a full example:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;

use Parse::FixedLength;
use Data::Dumper;
my $parser = Parse::FixedLength->new([
          field1 => '12R0:1:12',
          field2 => '2:13:14',
          field3 => '5R0:15:19',
          field4 => '10R0:20:29',
          field5 => '2R0:30:31',
          field6 => '3R0:32:34'
          ], {trim => '1'});

#$parser->{TPAD}[0] = qr/^0+(?=\d)/;   # Modification suggested by @bolav

while (<DATA>) {
    warn "No record terminator found!\n" unless chomp;
    warn "Short Record!\n" unless $parser->length == length;
    my $data = $parser->parse($_);
    for my $val (values %$data) {
        $val =~ s/^$/0/
    }
    #s/(\w+)/\u\L$1/g for @$data{qw(first_name last_name)};
    print Dumper $data;
}

__DATA__
119401122910XX42152931177771001000
119401122910XX42152931177771001010
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'field1' => '119401122910',
                 'field5' => '1',
                 'field2' => 'XX',
                 'field3' => '42152',
                 'field4' => '9311777710',
                 'field6' => '0'
               }, 'Parse::FixedLength::HashAsObj::Href1' );
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'field1' => '119401122910',
                 'field5' => '1',
                 'field2' => 'XX',
                 'field3' => '42152',
                 'field4' => '9311777710',
                 'field6' => '10'
               }, 'Parse::FixedLength::HashAsObj::Href1' );
```

Comment: Thanks @7stud. I know you will not know this from reading just this question but I do have 1000s of fields so I wanted to avoid looping through the parsed values. Also, the number of records can be in the 5-50MM range so fixing directly at the parser will be more efficient.

Comment: @Ecognium, *so fixing directly at the parser will be more efficient*--I do not see why that is necessarily true. And, if you want efficiency, I would look elsewhere, i.e. use `unpack()` directly.

Comment: Btw, besides efficiency I am also making my parsing a bit maintainable but reading from a config file and create the specification that `Parse::FixedLength`. I will be interested in learning about other ways of doing it, however.

Comment: @Ecognium, See the example I posted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unpack()` directly:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;

use Data::Dumper;

=begin
print " ";

for my $i (1..3) {
    printf '%10s', $i;
}
print("\n");

say "0123456789" x 4;
say "119401122910XX42152931177771001000";

--output:--
          1         2         3
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
119401122910XX42152931177771001000
=cut

# @12 => start at index position 12 in the record (0 based indexing)
# A5  => read 5 characters
my $pattern = <<'END_OF_PATTERN';

@0      A12 
@12     A2
@14     A5
@19     A10
@29     A2
@31     A3

END_OF_PATTERN


while (my $line = <DATA>) {

    my @fields = unpack $pattern, $line;

    for my $field (@fields[-2, -1]) {

        $field =~ s/
                        ^       #Match start of string, followed by...
                        0*      #A literal 0, zero or more times (greedy), followed by...
                        (\d+)   #A digit, one or more times, captured in group 1, followed by...
                        $       #The end of the string.
                  /$1/xms;   #Replace all the above with capture group 1.      
    }

    say Dumper @fields;
    say '-' x 10;
}


__DATA__
119401122910XX42152931177771001000
119401122910XX42152931177771001010
```

output:

```
$VAR1 = '119401122910';
$VAR2 = 'XX';
$VAR3 = '42152';
$VAR4 = '9311777710';
$VAR5 = '1';
$VAR6 = '0';

----------
$VAR1 = '119401122910';
$VAR2 = 'XX';
$VAR3 = '42152';
$VAR4 = '9311777710';
$VAR5 = '1';
$VAR6 = '10';

----------
```

Note that you can start at any index you want, you can reread parts of the record, etc. For instance:

```
@0  A10    #Start at index 0, read 10 characters
@0  A5     #Go back to index 0, read 5 charters
@20 A2     #Jump to index 20, read 2 characters
@18 A12    #Go back to index 18, read 12 characters
```